# study methods for first year phd courses in econ

Tags: econometrics

I'd really like some tips on how to master the material for first year phd econometrics (texts: hayashi chap 1 -3, - econometrics, casella and berger 5 - 8th chapter - statistical inference) apart from doing problem sets set by professor on my own and struggling through them :) I have a month and 10 days and get stuck easily while solving problems.

I am a self-taught mathematician (multivariable calc, linear algebra, single variable) and so I don't quite know how to utilise the tools in my toolbox although I know them in theory, if that makes sense. With practice questions, I start seeing a pattern and I am not seeing one in metrics yet. constructive advice much appreciated

Comment: one piece of advice is to do casella and berger first ( not just the 3 chapters ) and then, do econometrics second and maybe start out with a less dense econometrics text such as johnston or baltagi. If you're a math person, then the issue is background and notation rather than math. If you're doing a Ph.D then the classes itself might help also. No need to learn all the material on your own.